# How to handle daily calculations in a web application (Google Firebase/NestJS)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, microservices, nestjs

I am building a web app with the following stack:

- UI - React
- Backend framework - NestJS
- Infrastructure - Google Firestore document DB, services deployed in Heroku

I need to calculate finance portfolio metrics on a daily basis for all users and display them when the user logs in. I am in a bit of a dilemma what approach to take and I have several ideas, so I hope you can give me some guidance.

**Scheduled microservice**
I can build and schedule a microservice in Python (the finance framework is in Python) that will run every day and calculate the needed metrics for the users and update the database. Seems straightforward but it might consume a lot of compute resources, especially when the user base grows large.

**Cloud Functions**
Google Firestore supports cloud functions that can trigger on specific events. I can leverage that and run the calculation microservice when the data is requested - that way I will calculate the information only on-demand. The downside is that if the data has not been requested for a long time, I will have to calculate the metrics for a larger period of time and this might take a while.

P.S. Just saw that there are also scheduled cloud functions - possible implementation might check if the data is calculated today (user has logged in at least once) and if not, calculate it.

I will be happy to discuss any other options that might be available.

Comment: Correct me if I understood wrong, your users store daily finance info in individual firestore docs. At times, you might need to aggregate them and display them to the users? Right?

Comment: Yes - each user has a single document, where the daily data is stored and has to be displayed in a chart when he/she logs in. But the data has to be calculated for each day (portfolio performance) based on the financial market data for the current day.

Comment: Even though I am a big fan of Firebase, the only place where I stay away from using Firebase is finance apps. As you scale the app there might be need for more graphs, calculations based on week by week performance etc, something that currently only SQL deals well. Not saying that you shouldn't use Firebase, but if you have time, do give it a thought as well.

Comment: A good method with just firebase might be using Scheduled Microservices on a weekly basis for inactive users and using daily CF for active users. The best answer would depend on how you have structured the data and your DAU.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and insights! Personally, I was thinking that at some point I might need a second database provider for some of the data, so your comment makes perfect sense. I will explore if any SQL would be a better choice at least for the metrics.

Comment: Regarding SQL, since I'm not that experienced there, what would be the implementation approach - stored procedures that run every day?